# How to set location of screen capture from control strip to clipboard?

Tags: copy-paste, touch-bar

If I put the screenshot widget on my control strip (touch bar), it currently doesn't give me any option to copy the screenshot to the clipboard. Is there a way I can set it up to do this instead of saving a file?